# 'Object' object had no attitude 'name' discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make an id converter that converts any id to name.

```
@bot.command()
async def idconv(ctx, *, arg):
    id=int(arg) 
    conv=discord.Object(id)
    await ctx.send(conv.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you are trying to get a users name from their ID.
discord.py offers a class called Member that does it for you

```
import discord

@bot.command()
async def idconv(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(member.name)
```

While creating a `discord.Object` with an `id` is useful for banning\unbanning a user who doesn't share a guild with your bot, it isn't useful for your case.
Here is the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) for `discord.Member`.

Here the command `idconv` accepts arguments like user-id, name, nickname and tries to convert it into a Member object.
There might be instances where the ID of the member you provided may not share a server with the bot, and hence `member` ends up being `None` , resulting in any operation with `member` raising an error.

You can account for that by checking it beforehand

```
if member: #or if member is not None
 await ctx.send(member.name)
else:
 await ctx.send("Could not find a user with that ID")
```

If you use [bot.fetch_user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20fetch#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_user), you
can fetch any discord user by their ID, if found it returns an [User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User) object,
which is similar to Member but has overall lesser information.